# subprocess.check_output для команды из нескольких слов

Tags: python, python-3.6, subprocess

Использую бота в вк для управления сервером. Хочу использовать `subprocess.check_output` для этого. Но если передавать команду из нескольких слов, например, df -h, то вызывается ошибка. Команды типа uptime,reboot,ifconfig работают отлично. Вот мой код:

```py
command="df -h"
res=subprocess.check_output(command)
output=str(res)
```

Как можно реализовать выполнение команд состоящих из более чем одного слова?

Comment: А что говорится в ошибке и как вы её поняли?

Comment: @0xdb , Ошибка выглядит так: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'df -h': 'df -h'`. Причём я пробовал многие команды, но ответ приходил нормально только в том случае, если команда состояла из одного слова

Comment: Неужели вы её не поняли? Переделайте  command в лист - `command=["df", "-h"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `os.popen` (не хуже subprocess):

```
import os 
res=os.popen(command).read()
```

Comment: Идеально. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Команда передается с помощью: `list`

```
command=["df", "-h"]
res=subprocess.check_output(command)
output=str(res)
print(output)
```